# Kali Linux display flashing repeatedly after install Nvidia

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, kali-linux

Anyone know why my display flashing repeatedly [link](https://youtu.be/Y0MnpDI1ydE) after install NVIDIA GPU Drivers [link](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/install-nvidia-drivers-on-kali-linux/). The flashing happen if I enable "Allow G-SYNC/G-SYNC Compatible" in Nvidia X Server Settings. And if I disable it, the display working fine but after I restart the flashing comeback and I just need to open Nvidia X Server Settings to fix it.

So everytime I open my PC, I need to open Nvidia X Server Settings and close it.

Anyone know how to permanently fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable display compositing then issue resolved.
Settings > Windows Manager Tweaks > Compositor > untick Enable display compositing

Thank you all.